# Calling function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, autorun

I'm quite new to VBA, so I could be doing something entirely wrong or it could also just be a ridiculous little mistake/lack of knowledge. So if you have an easier method to do what I'd like to do (explained below), I'm open for any solution.

So I want to count the cells that have a specific background color.

For that, I have this in a module:

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

It works, it does count the specific cells with `=CountCellsByColor(B2:B83,H2)` (`B2:B83` is the range, `H2` is the cell I use as an example of that background color. I count `C2:C83` and `D2:D83` also in separate cells)

But I'd like it to execute automatically once a cell's background color changes in the given range.

For that, in the Worksheet's code I put this:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2:$D$83" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call CountCellsByColor()
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but I get a "compile error: argument not optional" error message

How do you think I should make it work automatically? How do I call the function in this sub?

Comment: Can you also show an example of how you THINK it should be called? I'm not sure what you're having trouble with? Or if you got an error message when you tried, what did the message say?

Comment: @Phanti I believe `Call` is being depreciated, and should be unnecessary.

Comment: @Mistella 
What I tried: 

```
'Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2:$D$83" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call CountCellsByColor()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub'
```

What I got was a compile error: argument not optional error message.

Comment: There is no work sheet change that triggers when a cells color is changed. If it is your macro that makes the colors change then call your function there

Comment: @AlexFindley Your function has two parameters. When it's being called in a function, you need to give it the parameters to use (like when you used it in the worksheet)

Comment: @AlexFindley For capturing cell color changes, check out this [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/574405-capturing-cell-color-change-vba.html)

Comment: @Mistella 

I tried that too. (realizing I didn't tell you any info beforehand, sorry) 

So if I try this: 

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2:$D$83" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call CountCellsByColor (B2:D83,H2)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub

Then I get a compile error at the ':' between B2 and D83. Compile error: expected: list separator or )

Comment: @AlexFindley , I edited your question to reflect your comment _"@Mistella What I tried: ..."_,

Comment: @Alex, as you are discovering,  automatically responding to a cell colour change is hard, and not well solved by any means.  You would be better to reevaluate your design. If you post _why_ you want to do this,  we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Range("I4").Value = CountCellsByColor(Range("B2:D83"), Range("H2"))

This will call your function, however like Chris Neilsen said, I would stay away from the Change event.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a lot of tiny details that need clarifying.

First, a `Worksheet_Change` function does not capture color changes. If the color is changing due to a function/sub you wrote, you should call your function where the change occurs. If the change is done by a user, the best reference I've found is [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/574405-capturing-cell-color-change-vba.html).

---

Second, the if-statement `If Target.Address = "$B$2:$D$83" Then` will only return true if the "Target" is all of those cells. If the target it only one or some of the cells from that range, the if-statement will return false. I would recommending an if-statement more like:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2:D83")) Is Nothing
```

---

Third, you need to add the parameters to the function call, such as:

```
CountCellsByColor(Target.Worksheet.Range("B2:D83"),Target.Worksheet.Range("H2"))
```

`Target.Worksheet` refers to the worksheet which the target is on/in. The `.Range` goes to the cells on the selected worksheet while the `"B2:D83"` are the addresses of the desired cells.

However, please note that this will not currently assign the output of `CountCellsByColor` to anything, so the result will be lost unless you assign it to a variable or a worksheet cell.